# Razor pages can't bind enum to dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have this dropdown on a razor page that's inside an Area. I've tried many options and the result is always an empty input. This is the most commonly suggested solution on stackoverflow:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Transaction.TransactionType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Transaction.TransactionType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<TransactionType>()" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Transaction.TransactionType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

I thought the problem was that the models folder was in the root folder of the application but it doesn't work when I try to use the same enum in a form in the root folder. This is my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: I think you missed @ in razor code
     <select asp-for="Transaction.TransactionType" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<TransactionType>()" class="form-control" />

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of `TransactionType` looks like this:

```
public enum TransactionType 
    {
        TransactionType1 = 0,
        TransactionType2 = 1,
        TransactionType3 = 2
    }
```

Try to use:

```
<select asp-for="Transaction.TransactionType"  class="form-control">
        @foreach (var item in Html.GetEnumSelectList<TransactionType>())
        {
            <option value=@item.Value>@item.Text</option>
        }
    </select>
```